# TortoiseSVN Commit htdocs?

Tags: windows-vista, permissions, tortoisesvn

Trying to version control my project that's sitting in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs` using TortoiseSVN. I can't commit it though because Tortoise doesn't have permission to create the `.svn` file in that folder (anywhere in Program Files?). How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you try to create the folder manually?

Comment: The `.svn` folder? What benefit would that be? It still wouldn't be allowed to throw its files in there, and there's not a chance in hell I'm manually creating 50 `.svn` folders to version this monstrosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the permissions on that folder accordingly:
right-click on folder, chose "properties". The "security" tab shows you which user has full access - add yourself to that list.

After that, you (the logged on user) have full access to that folder and you can checkout/update without problems.

Please **do not** run Tortoise or explorer in Administrator mode!

Comment: An error occurred while applying security information to: C:\... Access denied. Why is it denying me? I have admin rights!

Comment: ...seems I didn't own some of the subfolders, so I had to re-grant myself ownership and apply it to the subfolders too. All these "security" features are highly annoying.

Comment: And now SVN is telling me I have to run 'clean up' first, but of course that fails too. Completely ridiculous. So I had to check everything out again, manually copy over the unversioned files, and re-commit. Just to version-control my website. And people wonder why not everyone uses SVN...

Comment: And the empty folder *I* just created, *I* don't own... I don't get it. What security benefit is this?

Answer (score -1):

Run Tortoise as [Administrator](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistasecurity/thread/264aabc2-04ce-4d5d-b3e8-f2ce9996438b) mode.

Comment: Thought about that already, but it's shell-integrated. I have to right-click and go SVN Commit just to get to it.

Comment: are you logged in to the system as Administrator?

Comment: I have administrator privileges, but I'm not logged in as 'Administrator'.